# Why are these subsets of $P$ not subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Check whether following sets are subspaces of $P$ $(P = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots + a_nx^n)$?

1. $\{p \in P \mid \text{degree of }p \ge 5\}$
2. $\{p \in P \mid \text{degree of }p = 4\}$

I think they are subspaces but answer is showing they are not. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: So many reasons.... but essentially they boil down to “the sum of two elements of the set need not be in the set”.

Comment: Fix an $n≥4$ then $p_1=x^n$ and $p_2 =-x^n$ both $p_1$ and $p_2$ belong the sets you mention in $1$ and $2$ but their addition $p_1+p_2 =0$ does not which means closure wrt to addition is not satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

They don't contain the zero polynomial.